# 'git push heroku master' command returns 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository'

Tags: heroku

When I type, `git push heroku master`, I get:

```
!  No such app as sleepy-headland-6232.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I do `git remote -v`, I get:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:sleepy-headland-6232.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:sleepy-headland-6232.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:fackthisshit/github.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:fackthisshit/github.git (push)
```

Therefore I do `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:sleepy-headland-6232.git`, but then I get `fatal: remote heroku already exists`.

It's like an infinite loop of girder. How can I get out of this loop?

Comment: Check on heroku.com if that app exists under your account, if not, ask the owner to add you as a collaborator.

Comment: ohh.. is that the problem?

Comment: how can i do that? the owner is mattan griffel from one month rails.

Comment: how can i solve this????

Answer (score 34):

You don't need to create a new app, sometimes when you rename the app in Heroku you lose the connection to the remote.

To fix it

Just remove the old heroku remote with:

```
    git remote rm heroku
```

and add the new one:

```
    git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:name-to-the-new-one
```

if you don't know the link address, you can get it in heroku dashboard, in the settings of the app. And that's it.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed the issue for me where I accidentally created multiple heroku apps for the same git repo.  You want to add .git at the end:  git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:name-to-the-new-one.git

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku app doesn't exist. If your try to load the page http://sleepy-headland-6232.herokuapp.com in your browser, you will get this message:

```
Heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

To create a new heroku app, you can do it either via their website o with their command line tool like this: `$ heroku apps:create name_of_your_app`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but later I found out the reason: `git` default branch is `main` now and not `master`.

So use  `git push heroku main` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

just use the following command

```
git push origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have such issue as above, focus on the message "Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

it implies that

1. You tried deploying with no credentials or wrong credentials.
   this can be achieved by with `heroku login`
2. The remote to local repository does not exist even though the app does. so to add the remote to local, do this

   heroku git:remote -a appname